# Grey cloud around smoke simulation?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am getting a grey cloud around my actual smoke simulation. Do you know how can I solve this issue?
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a screenshot of your domain material this is just a guess, but it looks like apart from having your smoke you have set the *Emission Strength* in the *Principled Volume* node to a value > 0. Without connecting any density or flame information to the emission and not setting a different color, the whole domain (or in your case the *Adaptive Domain* since it's not looking like a full cube) will be emitting white light.

Comment: You were right. The shader had a .1 emission ....that solved. The domain was a rectangle, but was not set to adaptive. Now I made it a cube and turn on adaptive.